# not able to use jenkins Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have set up the plugin with reference from Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin. However I am getting these logs:

```
Triggering this remote job: remoteJob
Not checking if the remote job remoteJob is building.
Triggering remote job now.
Remote Jenkins server returned empty response or invalid JSON - but we can still proceed with the remote build.
Checking parameters of #2
Remote Jenkins server returned empty response or invalid JSON - but we can still proceed with the remote build.
Query failed.
Checking parameters of #1
Checking parameters of #3
Remote Jenkins server returned empty response or invalid JSON - but we can still proceed with the remote build.
Query failed.
Checking parameters of #0
Remote Jenkins server returned empty response or invalid JSON - but we can still proceed with the remote build.
Query failed.
```

I am able to trigger the remote job but not able to determine it's status.
My requirement is to trigger this remote job(remoteJob) on jenkins-B from jenkins-A and get it's build status on jenkins-A so that I can take action based on status.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I am using a python script using jenkins REST APIs to trigger and get build status from a remote jenkins server.
First determine if build is queued using `<jenkins_url>/queue/api/json` API. 
Then call /job//lastBuild/api/json to get the build status.